# "When a new email arrives in a shared mailbox (V2)" never get trigger

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, exchange-online

I have defined this "When a new email arrives in a shared mailbox (V2)" using a service account:-

[image]

, Where the Original Mailbox Address field is an environment variable which contain the shared mail box (different from the service account i used to create the workflow):-

[image]

and the From field is an environment variable >> which contain a personal outlook email address.. now when using the personal email address i send an email with attachment to shared mail box, the workflow will never get triggered..

what could be the reason?

Comment: Please provide your complete flow.